# Wie bezieht sich man auf Musik, die kein regelrechtes Lied ist?

Tags: single-word-request

Ich suche ein Wort, das Musik beschreibt, die im strengsten Sinne des Wortes kein Lied ist. Gleichzeitig würde ich auch gerne den spezifischen Begriff vermeiden.  Weder will ich

> *Ich mag {dieses Streichquartett · diese Sonate · diesen Bebop} sehr!*

sagen – denn ich bräuchte keine haargenaue Beschreibung – noch

> *Ich mag dieses Lied sehr!*

da es einfach total falsch wäre (und sogar ein bisschen idiotisch klingen würde).

**Frage:** Was könnte ich stattdessen sagen? Z.B. ist *Werk* oder *Stück* [1] in Ordnung?

---

[1] Die direkte Übersetzung aus dem Spanischen.

Comment: Ich hätte "Stück" oder, wenn der Zusammenhang es erfordert, "Musikstück" gesagt. "Werk" ist natürlich auch gut.

Comment: Einige Vorschläge: klassische Musik, Instrumentalmusik (Musik ohne Singstimmen), Sinfonie?

Comment: @HectorLector *klassische Musik* kommt mir irgendwie eher als ein Kollektiv vor. *Instrumentalmusik* vielleicht, so, danke.

Comment: Soll "hauptsächlich keinen" bedeuten "wenig, kaum"?

Comment: Genau genommen ist ein Lied eine sehr spezielle Form eines Gesangsstückes. Weitere Mitglieder dieser Kategorie wären beispielsweise: Arie, Duett, Choral, Hymne. Beim Lied sind m.E. kennzeichnend: keine Begleitung, oder Begleitung nur durch einzelnes Instrument (Gitarre, Klavier) sowie ein Text, der ungesungen als Gedicht anzusprechen wäre.

Comment: @Ingo Bin mir nicht sicher; denn Mahler hat beisplielsweise »Des Knaben Wunderhorn« komponiert, ein Orchesterlied.

Comment: @userunknown Also, den Begriff *Lied* –den allgemeinen, nicht den akademischen Begriff, die auf Deutschsprächiges Lied (Schubert, Schumann, Wolf) sich bezieht– zu definieren, fällt mir schwer, sogar auf meiner Muttersprache. Deswegen habe ich wieder ein Edit gemacht.

Comment: @c.p. Ok, ich wollte keine letztgültige Definition geben, sondern eine Handreichung, wann das Wort "Lied" höchstwahrscheinlich angebracht ist. Darüberhinaus mag es Verwendungen geben, die dann halt aber genauer bezeichnet werden können (Kunst~, Orchester~).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ich denke, *das Stück* bzw. *das Musikstück* sind die darauf passenden neutralen Begriffe. Sie funktionieren für musikalische Kompositionen aller Art. *Das Werk* passt, wenn es um etwas wirklich herausragend wertvolles geht.

Zu beachten ist noch, dass die Begriffe *Stück*, *Musikstück* und *Werk* mehr aus dem Blickwinkel des Musikers bzw. Musikkenners verwendet werden, also als relativ gewählte Ausdrucksweise tendenziell musiktheoretische Begriffe.

Comment: Ohne den zweiten Absatz fände ich die Antwort noch besser.

Answer (score 3):

"Komposition" könnte passen. Auch wenn es vorwiegend eher für klassische Musikstücke verwendet wird, so kann es auch andere Genres abdecken, indem man z. B. sagt: gute Komposition aus Gesang und Begleitung oder Ähnliches.